# Python execution from php

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I am calling python from php using "exec('python args')" command. This command is not working for more than 1 minute, but still python is running in the background and php is aborting. In this case some times there multiple calls to python. 
To increase the execution time I modified:

- `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` : `max_execution_time = 900`
- `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`  : `request_terminate_timeout=900`
- `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` : `http{ fastcgi_read_timout=900;}`

If the execution time is less than 1minute no issues python and php both are working.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue have you tried increasing the execution time ?

Comment: @Krish I have tried that also, still I am facing same issue.

Comment: I would highly recommend to use http://gearman.org/ or any other kind of worker implementation instead of what you try to do.

Comment: @burzum I am new to this can you explain how to use?

Comment: How about reading the docs? http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php

Comment: @burzum Thank You I will go through the Document.

Comment: `but still python is running in the background` when the php process dies - so will any spawned process unless it was started with NOHUP. As burzum hinted, using a job queue is a much better idea